# Different versions of python when running cmd as admin, how do I alter admin version?

Tags: python, windows

I'm having some trouble tracking down where my pip modules are going, and I finally found what seems to be the root of the issue when I did a "pip list" command in two separate cmd windows.

One window was running as admin, and the other not.  They showed two completely different lists of modules installed.  When I ran "python" in each window, one started `python 3.4.3`, and the other `python 3.5.0a2`.

The reason I'm doing this in two separate types of windows is because I'm running into "access is denied" errors when trying to install modules with pip.  (For example, `requests`.)

When I check my PATH variable, it points to `C:\Program Files\Python 3.5`.  **Is there an admin PATH variable somewhere that I can modify so that I can run python3.5 as admin**?

Can someone help me understand how I can get around `access is denied` without using admin cmd, or how I can change admin Path variable, or something?

I'm running Windows 7, 64 bit, with several versions of python installed. 2.7, 3.3, 3.4.3, 3.5.0a2.  I can get more refined details if I need to.

Edit Addition:  I'd like to use virtualenv with python3.5, but when I try to install it with `pip install virtualenv`, I get `Permission denied` error.

Comment: Try googling virtualenv - it's most likely a correct approach for this problem. Not only you'll have isolated Python environments for each Python version, you may have isolated Python environments for each project you are developing.

Comment: Windows concatenates the user's `PATH` to the system `PATH`. It seems you're using a standard user, so when you elevate to admin it's as a completely different user. That's atypical on a personal Windows box. With UAC you're normally a restricted admin, and starting an elevated process uses your unrestricted token.

Comment: You can simply use `py -3.5 -m pip`. But please first update to 3.5.1. 3.5.0a2 is the second alpha release and was only distributed for testing.

Comment: How do I get virtualenv with python 3.5 when I get `access is denied` errors when I use python 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

Although you are running Python on a Windows Machine - I am assuming a Client i.e. Desktop. You should go and look at **Virtual Python Environments** - there are lots of resources documenting how this is accomplished...

You are directly manipulating the **System** copy of the Python Environment and 1 mistake will screw the whole lot up. Much better (and safer) for either project/Projects(s) to share a Virtual Env - which you can then either upgrade using pip requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm trying to install virtualenv to work with python3.5, and I keep getting `access is denied` errors.

Comment: Ok - this is rather "chicken and egg"... as you are still trying to add a new module to the "admin" copy of Python. But there is a solution  -  You need to download the **Source** of Python (say 3.5) - and then compile and install it **Locally** i.e. you have your own version of Python - at this point you can install what every libraries to your own version of Python that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution anywhere to this, so I just deleted every trace of Python from my computer and installed Anaconda.

I don't feel this was a very informed or optimal solution, but I now have consistent behavior in various places.  Also, the Anaconda installer seems much more smooth than the pip installer.

Comment: Did you try using `py -3.5 -m pip install ...` from an elevated command prompt? The new installer for 3.5 let's you install the py launcher to the system, even if installing Python just for the current user, so py.exe should be in the Windows directory and available without any `PATH` modification. I never touch `PATH` since I use py.exe and virtual environments.  If you're only using Python 3, use the standard library's venv module instead of virtualenv. It's integrated by design while virtualenv is a hack (useful, but a hack all the same).

Comment: I did try it last night, but I can't remember the problem.  At some point, an old install of python2.7 started showing up, and that's when I threw in the towel.